# How to write output in txtfile?in python 3.1

Tags: python

I have a afew results that I can print them like this :

```
print ("BugID : ", bugID, '\n' , "Bug Description : ", desc, '\n' , "Classification : ", classification, '\n', "Component : ", component, '\n', "Version : ", version, '\n',  "Operating System : ", opsystem, '\n',  "Status : ", status )
```

how can I write them in the txtfile?

Comment: You can follow the documentation here - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects It is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("log.txt","w") as my_log_file:
    print("a","bunch","of","stuff",file=my_log_file)
                                   # ^ this is the part thats important
```

I think is all you need

this is explained here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

```
# Open a file
fo = open("foo.txt", "wb")
fo.write( "Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n");

# Close opened file
fo.close()
```